# Using asynchronous obtained ListItem components from the state of a React component in Material-UI List for React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The List component from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list does not render asynchronous received elements, what to do?

The way I use my list in the render() method of the component:

```
<List children={this.state.elements} />
```

Filling my state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {elements: []};
}

async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({elements: this.getInitialState()});
}

async getInitialState() {
      var elements = [];
      const response = await fetch('api/endpoint/elements');
      const result = await response.json();
      if (result.status = "success") {
          elements.push(<ListItem primaryText="Dummy Data" />);
      }
      return elements;
  }
```

Comment: Couple things, I don't think `componentDidMount` is an asynchronous function and depending on the number of endpoints you're hitting it may make more sense to use redux and something like redux-saga to handle your state.

Comment: My application will rely heavy on endpoints, actually permanently showing to the user what the database holds by allowing him to navigate through a tree structure.

Comment: Alright, if you can provide a more complete working example I can help show you what you'll want to do.

Comment: This is actually everything there is right now, but I will try to look into redux.

Comment: Alrighty, I highly recommend [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) for your async actions! You can @ my username if you need any help.

Comment: @cssko Copy that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await getInitialState in componentDidMount.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const state = await this.getInitialState();
    this.setState({elements: state});
}
```

If you want to do something after setting the state use this Async wrapper of setState and await it

```
  setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept is okay and should work.

componentDidMount is the place to add async logic for small apps(see sagas, redux etc. for bigger apps).

your problem is that setState is not an async function, so the component's state cannot be properly set.

simply move all the ajax logic componentDidMount, when the ajax resolves, modify the state.

I never tried it with await, so I can't be sure it works with that, but it 100% works with Promises (fetch for example)

a tiny pseudo code :

```
componentDidMount(){
   //jquery's POST function, just as an example
   $.post(url).then(() => {
      this.setState({dataLoaded:true});
   });
}
```

Comment: componentDidMount is async function. You can await promises instead of `.then` chaining them.